# Get current page and run?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wish to have something in a simple extension that when you open it, it gets the page you are on in a variable, and it runs when you click on it, affecting that page.

For example;

```
var Page = //code to get page
document.getElementById("RandomId").innerHTML = Page;
```

On the current page

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var PageLink;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    PageLink= tab.url;
});

console.log(PageLink); //to verify
```